# How do I create a directory in webform for uploaded files

Tags: webforms

I wanted to use the 'file' field type in webform for file submission on my website, but I was getting this error message:

> The save directory could not be created. Check that the webform files
>   directory is writable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which system/server u r using?

Comment: You should take a look at [Securing file permissions and ownership](http://drupal.org/node/244924).

Answer (score 2):

First go to `"Administer -> Site Configuration -> File System -> File System Path"` configuration page. verify your file path and temp path given no error.

change permissions(writable) to files folder under "sites/default/files".

Comment: Thank you very much. I have created a form to browse and upload a file, but it is giving this error: • Warning: move_uploaded_file(public://webform/testing.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: "DrupalPublicStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_save_upload() (line 1528 of C:\inetpub\vhosts\uniontrusteeslimited.com\httpdocs\newsite\includes\file.inc).

The error comes up after clicking upload.

Comment: Continuation of the error message: • Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpE4EC.tmp' to 'public://webform/testing.docx' in file_save_upload() (line 1528 of C:\inetpub\vhosts\uniontrusteeslimited.com\httpdocs\newsite\includes\file.inc).
• File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Linux user go to your files directory and type the following command:

`chmod -R 0777` .

Comment: permissions should be `755`. `777` not recommended

Comment: 755 only works when the user the webserver runs as owns the files directory.

Answer (score 0):

if webserver user does not owns filesystem then use 775 at most